# Passing Numpy arrays to C code wrapped with Cython

Tags: arrays, numpy, cython

I have a small bit of existing C code that I want to wrap using Cython. I want to be able to set up a number of numpy arrays, and then pass those arrays as arguments to the C code whose functions take standard c arrays (1d and 2d). I'm a little stuck in terms of figuring out how to write the proper .pyx code to properly handle things.

There are a handful of functions, but a typical function in the file funcs.h looks something like:

```
double InnerProduct(double *A, double **coords1, double **coords2, const int len)
```

I then have a .pyx file that has a corresponding line:

```
cdef extern from "funcs.h":
    double InnerProduct(double *A, double **coords1, double **coords2, int len)
```

where I got rid of the *const* because cython doesn't support it. Where I'm stuck is what the wrapper code should then look like to pass a MxN numpy array to the **coords1 and **coords2 arguments.

I've struggled to find the correct documentation or tutorials for this type of problem. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple wrapping of C code with cython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046305/simple-wrapping-of-c-code-with-cython)

Comment: I have a [Cython post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41944883/verifying-compatibility-in-compiling-extension-types-and-using-them-with-cdef) you may be able to provide insight on.

Answer (score 4):

You probably want Cython's "typed memoryviews"  feature, which you can read about in full gory detail [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html).  This is basically the newer, more unified way to work with numpy or other arrays.  These can be exposed in Python-land as numpy arrays, or you can export them to Python (for example, [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays)).  You have to pay attention to how the striding works and make sure you're consistent about e.g. C-contiguous vs. FORTRAN-like arrays, but the docs are pretty clear on how to do that.

Without knowing a bit more about your function it's hard to be more concrete on exactly the best way to do this - i.e., is the C function read-only for the arrays?  (I think yes based on the signature you gave, but am not 100% sure.)  If so you don't need to worry about making copies if needed to get C-contiguous states, because the C function doesn't need to talk back to the Python-level numpy array.  But typed memoryviews will let you do any of this with a minimum of fuss.

Answer (score 0):

The cython interface code should be created according to the tutorial given [here](http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html).

To get a C pointer to the data in a numpy array, you should use the ctypes attribute of the numpy array, which is described [here](http://www.scipy.org/Cookbook/Ctypes).

Comment: Isn't this mixing two separate technologies (not that that's necessarily wrong)? I haven't seen any tutorials that suggest using ctypes with cython, and I would assume that there was a way to handle this completely in cython.

Comment: Numpy arrays always have the "ctypes" attribute which is a safe way to access their data as a C-pointer.  According to the documentation there are some equivalent ways of directly accessing the "data" attribute of the array, see http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ctypes.html#numpy-ndarray-ctypes.