# Optimizing my Cython/Numpy code? Only a 30% performance gain so far

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Is there anything I've forgotten to do here in order to speed things up a bit? I'm trying to implement an algorithm described in a book called Tuning Timbre Spectrum Scale. Also---if all else fails, is there a way for me to just write this part of the code in C, then be able to call it from python?

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

# DTYPE = np.float
ctypedef np.float_t DTYPE_t

np.seterr(divide='raise', over='raise', under='ignore', invalid='raise')

"""
I define a timbre as the following 2d numpy array:
[[f0, a0], [f1, a1], [f2, a2]...] where f describes the frequency
of the given partial and a is its amplitude from 0 to 1. Phase is ignored.
"""

#Test Timbre
# cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] t1 = np.array( [[440,1],[880,.5],[(440*3),.333]])

# Calculates the inherent dissonance of one timbres of the above form
# using the diss2Partials function
cdef DTYPE_t diss1Timbre(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] t):
    cdef DTYPE_t runningDiss1
    runningDiss1 = 0.0
    cdef unsigned int len = np.shape(t)[0]
    cdef unsigned int i
    cdef unsigned int j
    for i from 0 <= i < len:
        for j from i+1 <= j < len:
            runningDiss1 += diss2Partials(t[i], t[j])
    return runningDiss1

# Calculates the dissonance between two timbres of the above form 
cdef DTYPE_t diss2Timbres(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] t1, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] t2):
    cdef DTYPE_t runningDiss2
    runningDiss2 = 0.0
    cdef unsigned int len1 = np.shape(t1)[0]
    cdef unsigned int len2 = np.shape(t2)[0]
    runningDiss2 += diss1Timbre(t1)
    runningDiss2 += diss1Timbre(t2)
    cdef unsigned int i1
    cdef unsigned int i2
    for i1 from 0 <= i1 < len1:
        for i2 from 0 <= i2 < len2:
            runningDiss2 += diss2Partials(t1[i1], t2[i2])
    return runningDiss2

cdef inline DTYPE_t float_min(DTYPE_t a, DTYPE_t b): return a if a <= b else b

# Calculates the dissonance of two partials of the form [f,a]
cdef DTYPE_t diss2Partials(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=1] p1, np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=1] p2):
    cdef DTYPE_t f1 = p1[0]
    cdef DTYPE_t f2 = p2[0]
    cdef DTYPE_t a1 = abs(p1[1])
    cdef DTYPE_t a2 = abs(p2[1])

    # In order to insure that f2 > f1:
    if (f2 < f1):
        (f1,f2,a1,a2) = (f2,f1,a2,a1)

    # Constants of the dissonance curves
    cdef DTYPE_t _xStar
    _xStar = 0.24
    cdef DTYPE_t _s1
    _s1 = 0.021
    cdef DTYPE_t _s2
    _s2 = 19
    cdef DTYPE_t _b1
    _b1 = 3.5
    cdef DTYPE_t _b2
    _b2 = 5.75

    cdef DTYPE_t a = float_min(a1,a2)
    cdef DTYPE_t s = _xStar/(_s1*f1 + _s2)
    return (a * (np.exp(-_b1*s*(f2-f1)) - np.exp(-_b2*s*(f2-f1)) ) )

cpdef dissTimbreScale(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] t,np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=1] s):
    cdef DTYPE_t currDiss
    currDiss = 0.0;
    cdef unsigned int i
    for i from 0 <= i < s.size:
        currDiss += diss2Timbres(t, transpose(t,s[i]))
    return currDiss

cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] transpose(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t,ndim=2] t, DTYPE_t ratio):
    return np.dot(t, np.array([[ratio,0],[0,1]]))
```

Link to code: [Cython Code](http://pastebin.com/JYfBhcp3)

Comment: like this: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/external.html and http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/clibraries.html ?

Comment: No, I'm only using Cython to speed up an algorithm which was originally written in straight-up Python.

Comment: For python -> C, see SO [simple-wrapping-of-c-code-with-cython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046305/simple-wrapping-of-c-code-with-cython)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some things that I noticed:

1. Use `t1.shape[0]` instead of `np.shape(t1)[0]` and in so on in other places.
2. Don't use `len` as a variable because it is a built-in function in Python (not for speed, but for good practice). Use L or something like that.
3. Don't pass two-element arrays to functions unless you really need to. Cython checks the buffer every time you do pass an array. So, when using `diss2Partials(t[i], t[j])` do `diss2Partials(t[i,0], t[i,1], t[j,0], t[j,1])` instead and redefine `diss2Partials` appropriately.
4. Don't use `abs`, or at least not the Python one. It is having to convert your C double to a Python float, call the abs function, then convert back to a C double. It would probably be better to make an inlined function like you did with `float_min`.
5. Calling `np.exp` is doing a similar thing to using `abs`. Change `np.exp` to `exp` and add `from libc.math cimport exp` to your imports at the top.
6. Get rid of the `transpose` function completely. The `np.dot` is really slowing things down, but there really is no need for matrix multiplication here anyway. Rewrite your `dissTimbreScale` function to create an empty matrix, say `t2`. Before the current loop, set the second column of `t2` to be equal to the second column of `t` (using a loop preferably, but you could probably get away with a Numpy operation here). Then, inside of the current loop, put in a loop that sets the first column of `t2` equal to the first column of `t` times `s[i]`. That's what your matrix multiplication was really doing. Then just pass `t2` as the second parameter to `diss2Timbres` instead of the one returned by the `transpose` function.

Do 1-5 first because they are rather easy. Number 6 may take a little more time, effort and maybe experimentation, but I suspect that it may also give you a significant boost in speed.

Comment: I'd replaced Numpy exps with Python exps, but whoa---using C exps results in a good 2x speedup! Now looking into #3 and #6...

Comment: Alright, implemented #3 and #6 and juggled around with the way the code handles unsorted lists (instead of sorting and then passing them, it leaves them unsorted and expects the next function to compare each pair of elements in order to use them in the correct order)...anyway, thanks a lot for the comment, it made my code a good 2.5x faster (after I had already made it 15x faster)!

Comment: Hmmm...maybe I should add a quicksort function so that I don't have to do all of those comparisons...meh

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
for i from 0 <= i < len:
    for j from i+1 <= j < len:
        runningDiss1 += diss2Partials(t[i], t[j])
return runningDiss1
```

bounds checking is performed for each array lookup, use the decorator `@cython.boundscheck(False)` before the function, and then cast to an unsigned int type before using i and j as the indices. Look up the [cython for Numpy tutorial](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/numpy_tutorial.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I would profile your code in order to see which function takes the most time. If it is `diss2Timbres` you may benefit from the package "numexpr".

I compared Python/Cython and Numexpr for one of my functions ([link to SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28387340/performance-comparison-fortran-numpy-cython-and-numexpr)). Depending on the size of the array, numexpr outperformed both, Cython and Fortran.

NOTE: Just figured out this post is really old...