# convert numpy array to cython pointer

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I have a numpy array which came from a `cv2.imread` and so has `dtype = np.uint8` and `ndim = 3`.

I want to convert it to a Cython `unsigned int*` for use with an external cpp library.

I am trying `cdef unsigned int* buff = <unsigned int*>im.data` however I get the error `Python objects cannot be cast to pointers of primitive types`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: The answers to this one probably help: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3046305/222914

Comment: Note also that `np.uint8` is `unsigned char`, not `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

thanks for your comments.  solved by:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=3, mode = 'c'] np_buff = np.ascontiguousarray(im, dtype = np.uint32)
cdef unsigned int* im_buff = <unsigned int*> np_buff.data
```

Comment: you should probably use `np.uint` instead of `np.uint32` (`unsigned int` might be 64-bit on some systems).

Comment: according to https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/tutorials-NumpyPointerToC, &np_buff[0,0,0] would be better than <unsigned int*> np_buff.data

Answer (score 12):

The more modern way would be to use a memoryview rather than a pointer:

```
cdef np.uint32_t[:,:,::1] mv_buff = np.ascontiguousarray(im, dtype = np.uint32)
```

The `[:,;,::1]` syntax tells Cython the memoryview is 3D and C contiguous in memory. The advantage of defining the type to be a memoryview rather than a numpy array is

1. it can accept any type that defines the buffer interface, for example the built in array module, or objects from the PIL imaging library.
2. Memoryviews can be passed without holding the GIL, which is useful for parallel code

To get the pointer from the memoryview get the address of the first element:

```
cdef np.uint32_t* im_buff = &mv_buff[0,0,0]
```

This is better than doing `<np.uint32_t*>mv_buff.data` because it avoids a cast, and casts can often hide errors.