# How to iterate over the items of a view?

Tags: cython

I have knowledge of C and Python, but I am new to Cython.

I have a view on a (contiguous) array of double. I want to iterate over the items of the view through a pointer and an index, as we would do in C. However, I cannot express that with Cython:

```
from cpython cimport array
import array

arr = array.array("d", (1,2,3,4))

cdef double[::1] view = arr[::1]
cdef unsigned l = len(view)
cdef double *ptr = view.as_doubles

# Iterate over the view items
cdef double acc = 0.0
cdef unsigned i
for i in range(l):
    acc += ptr[i]
```

The code above is rejected with an error:

```
a.pyx:8:5: Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mixed up the syntax for (untyped) arrays with `....as_doubles` and the syntax for (typed) memory views.

The correct code should have been:

```
cdef double *ptr = &view[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
acc += view[i]
```

There's really no point in involving pointers here - indexing a typed memoryviews should have comparable performance. (You may want to disable `boundschecking` and `wraparound` with the appropriate Cython compiler directives if you're sure that you don't need them while indexing)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, David. But admitting I really need a pointer to the underlying buffer (say, to pass that to an external C function `f(const double*, size_t)`). How could I do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14585530/4657412, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54832269/4657412

Comment: Indeed! I found that about at the same time as you pointed it to me! https://stackoverflow.com/a/75972960/2363712