# Trying to understand initialization of array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am working with C++ to construct an array, which is then passed into Python (similar to: [Embed python / numpy in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46493307/embed-python-numpy-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1)). I am new to C++ and I am confused with some of the details of the code. I'm hoping I can get an understanding of how this code works, because I need to change it. So my question is: what is this method of initializing an array?

```
const int SIZE{ 10 };
double(*c_arr)[SIZE]{ new double[SIZE][SIZE] };
```

For the record, I've been able to make this a rectangular array by calling:

```
const int numberRows = 5000;
const int numberColumns = 500;
double(*c_arr)[numberColumns]{ new double[numberRows][numberColumns] };
```

I fill the array:

```
// fill the array from a file
std::string line;
int row = 0;
int column = 0;
while (std::getline(dataFile, line)) {
    std::stringstream lineStream(line);
    std::string cell;
    while (std::getline(lineStream, cell, '\t')) {
        c_arr[row][column] = std::stod(cell);
        column++;
    }
    row++;
    column = 0;
    if (row == numberRows) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I still don't understand what is meant by `double(*c_arr)`. Whenever I try to initialize this array differently, I get errors. For example: `double *c_arr[numberRows][numberColumns];` raises errors when I try to fill the array `c_arr[row][column] = std::stod(cell);`. If I change the initialization to be: `double c_arr[numberRows][numberColumns];`, then I get a segmentation fault when run. What I'd like to eventually achieve is a function that returns a pointer to an array; something like:

```
double *load_data(int rows, int columns) {
    double(*c_arr)[columns]{ new double[rows][columns] };
    //fill array here
    return (c_arr)
}
```

When I construct such a function, I get an error at the second occurrence of the `columns` variable: `expression must have a constant value -- the value of parameter "columns" cannot be used as a constant`. I don't really how to do this, but I'm hoping that if I can understand the array initialization, I'll be able to properly construct the `load_data` function.

Comment: A pointer-to-array (`int (*p)[5]`) is different from an array-of-pointers (`int *p[5]`). I think this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: Ahh, that makes a little more sense, then. So, the parenthese around a pointer implies the pointer is pointing to the object? Something like this...?

Comment: It's the declaration syntax for variables. In complex cases, it's notoriously tricky, since we write something before the name (`p`), something after, and the order is not trivial to understand. Parentheses are needed in some cases to force the wanted type, as in the example I made above. `int (*p)[5]` means p is a pointer to an array of 5 ints. `int *p[5]` instead parses as `int *(p[5])` which is an array of 5 pointers to int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double(*c_arr)[SIZE]{ new double[SIZE][SIZE] };
```

The above is/can be read as:

> c_arr is a pointer to an array of size `SIZE`. Next, `new double[SIZE][SIZE]` creates a 2D array and also **returns** a pointer to its first element(which is also an array of double). Next, the pointer `c_arr` is initialized with the pointer **returned** in the last step from `new double[SIZE][SIZE]`;

Now lets take a look at:

```
double *c_arr[numberRows][numberColumns];
```

In this case, `c_arr` is a 2D array of pointers to double. And so you cannot initialize this 2D array of pointers with a single pointer like:

```
 double d=15; 
 double *c_arr[5][6]=&d ;//incorrect
```

Now coming to your **error**:

> When I construct such a function, I get an error at the second occurrence of the columns variable: expression must have a constant value -- the value of parameter "columns" cannot be used as a constant

This is because, in C++ the size of an array must be a **compile time constant**(`constant expression`). So for example,

```
int n = 10;
double arr[n]; //incorrect
```

The correct way would be:

```
const int n = 10;
double arr[n];//correct
```

So in your code the variable named `columns` is not a constant expression which is the reason you get the above mentioned error.

To correctly return a pointer to an array, you can modify your `load_data` function to look like:

```
auto load_data(int rows, int columns) -> double (*)[5]{

    double(*c_arr)[5]{ new double[4][5] };
    
    //fill array here
    return c_arr;
}
```

In the above modification of `load_data`, instead of using the numbers 4 and 5 you can use other constant expressions.

Comment: Thank you for this. Per the error, how can I pass such an argument into an array-construction function? Should it be `double *load_data(int rows, const int columns) {...}`? Also, I get an error on the return type if I initialize `c_arr` as `double(*c_arr)[numberCols]{ new double[numberRows][numberCols] };`. I thought I was returning a pointer, so this should work...?

Comment: @CopyOfA For returning a pointer through the `load_data` function you can use the method that i have added at the end of my answer. Check it out. Now the function `load_data` returns a pointer to an array of size 5 of `double`. Note again that i have given the example for particular numbers like 4 and 5. If you have some constant expressions then you can use those instead of the numbers 4 and 5. You should instead use dynamic sized containers like `std::vector`.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you use the function arguments `rows` or `columns`. How can I use function arguments to construct the array pointer? Is this not possible?

Comment: @CopyOfA Using the arguments `rows` and `columns` is **not possible** since they both are not constant expression. On the other hand if you use `std::vector` then you can avoid these problems altogether.

Comment: Hmmm... So, the array size has to be hard-coded?

Comment: @CopyOfA Basically yes **if** you use arrays. On the other hand if you use `std::vector` then you can use the passed arguments like `rows` and `columns`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239327/discussion-between-copyofa-and-anoop-rana).

Answer (score 2):

> what is this method of initializing an array?
>
> ```
> const int SIZE{ 10 };
> double(*c_arr)[SIZE]{ new double[SIZE][SIZE] };
> ```

`c_arr` is a pointer to `double[SIZE]` i.e. pointer to array of doubles.

`new double[SIZE][SIZE]` allocates a default initialised dynamic array of `double[SIZE]`. The result is a pointer to the first element. That pointer is used to initialise `c_arr`.

Comment: Thank you! More questions: When I initialize a rectangular array, I initialize `double(*c_arr)[numberColumns]{ new double[numberRows][numberColumns] }`. Why do I declare `numberColumns` to be the size of the dynamic array? Also, why can I not initialize the array pointer as `double *c_arr[numberRows][numberColumns]`?

Comment: @CopyOfA That's not what you  did. The size of the dynamic array is `numberRows`. You can initialise an array of pointers.

Comment: I'm a little confused. I thought the size of the array was `numberColumns`, since that is the first call (`double(*c_arr)[numberColumns]`).

Comment: @CopyOfA The size of the dynamic array is `numberRows`. The elements of the dynamic array are arrays whose size is `numberColumns`. `c_arr` points to the fist element.