# Cython passing int numpy array to C++

Tags: numpy, cython

First, I know this question appears similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17855032/7881370) but they are different. I'm struggling trying to pass int (int32) numpy array to C++ via Cython without copying. The files:

`doit.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "doit.h"
void run(int *x) {}
```

`doit.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef _DOIT_H_
#define _DOIT_H_
void run(int *);
#endif
```

`q.pyx`:

```py
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

cdef extern from "doit.h":
    void run(int* X)

def pyrun(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] X):
    X = np.ascontiguousarray(X)
    run(&X[0])
```

I compile with Cython. The error is:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
cdef extern from "doit.h":
    void run(int* X)

def pyrun(np.ndarray[np.int_t, ndim=1] X):
    X = np.ascontiguousarray(X)
    run(&X[0])
       ^
------------------------------------------------------------

py_cpp/q.pyx:9:8: Cannot assign type 'int_t *' to 'int *'
```

However, if I replace all occurrences of `int` to `double` (e.g. `int *x` to `double *x`, `int_t` to `double_t`), then all errors are gone.

How to solve the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `int_t` maps to `long` which is 8bytes on Linux but 4bytes on Windows. It is better to use `np.int32_t` which would be the same on all platforms

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/72471220/5769463